# Dojo (or alternative) generic input form, entirely based on schema definition

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to build somewhat of a similar application like PHPMyAdmin with Dojo.  Not quite as advanced as that, but similar, basically a CRUD system with Dojo presenting the view of a schema, populated with values coming from a database.

In OOP terms, I think I should be able to explain it as a car, bus and garage.

The schema for a car might be like

```
car: [
 {
  variableName: 'capacity',
  type: 'int',
  range: '0-6'
 },
 {
  variableName: 'fuelType',
  type: 'string'
 }
]

bus: [
 {
  variableName: 'capacity',
  type: 'int',
  range: '0-50'
 },
 {
  variableName: 'fuelType',
  type: 'string'
 }
]

garage: [
 {
  variableName: 'capacity',
  type: 'int',
  range: '0-10'
 },
 {
  variableName: 'buses',
  listType: 'car',
  range: '0-2'
 },
 {
  variableName: 'cars',
  listType: 'bus',
  range: '0-5',
  default: []
 }
]
```

That's the schema definition, then I'd want to be able to throw this type of 'garage' at my page,

```
garage: {
 capacity: 5,
 buses: [
  {
   capacity: 10,
   fuelType: 'petrol'
  }
 ]
}
```

and based on my schema, it'll show me a dynamic form with all of this 'garage' info.  I should be able to change the capacity, add a 'bus' to the 'buses' list and an empty list should be shown for the 'cars' that allow me to add a new one.  Again, in my head, I'd like it to get to something like PHPMyAdmin or that type of structure and I've seen a few database tools that their view is obviously designed and constrained by the schema that defines the database structure.

Now, I assume I'm going to have to do the majority of this myself, but I always find with Dojo there's a huge potential someone's already done a crazy amount of custom work that could everything that I've thought of and loads more, so it's always safe to ask :)

As always, huge thanks for any help I might get and I'll provide as much necessary info as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand using either dojox.grid.Datagrid + dojox.data.JsonRestStore(or any other to your liking) or the new dgrid (with new dojo.store.JsonRest)
Make the grid editables, use formatters if needed, cell types for different input types (select, input text fields, etc)

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/grid/DataGrid

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/data/JsonRestStore

or

http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/10/26/introducing-the-next-grid-dgrid/

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/store/JsonRest

hope this helps :)